# Java Can I Add Functions to a Collection for Executing in Sequence?

Tags: java

I'm new to Java. I want rewrite some Python code to Java to achieve basically the same functions. One part in my Python code is to execute the functions in sequence. Can I create a similar collection of methods in Java?

process_workflow.py

```
workflow = [
    stage1,
    stage2,
    stage3
]

def process_workflow(workflow: list):
    for stage in workflow:    # each 'stage' is a method
        stage()
```

The methods of each stage are defined in another Python script. stages.py

```
def stage1():
    ...

def stage2():
    ...

def stage3():
    ...
```

My tentative Java code:

```
class Stages {
    void stage1() {
    }
    void stage2() {
    }
    void stage3() {
    }
}
```

```
class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Stages stage_obj = new Stages();

        Collection workflow = new ArrayList();
        workflow.add(stage_obj.stage1);
        workflow.add(stage_obj.stage2);
        workflow.add(stage_obj.stage3);

        Iterator workflowIterator = workflow.iterator();
        // ...

    }
}
```

Comment: Try using the ``Callable`` interface

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22514947/call-methods-in-sequence

Comment: @Aniket Actually it does by using either lambdas or method references.

Answer (score 4):

You can do it in Java 8+ with [**Functional Interfaces**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/FunctionalInterface.html) and [**Method References**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html).

In your case, a `void` method with no parameters and no `throws` clause, your methods match the `Runnable` interface method:

> ```
> @FunctionalInterface
> public interface Runnable {
>     void run();
> }
> ```

So your code would be:

```
Stages stage_obj = new Stages();
List<Runnable> workflow = Arrays.asList(
    stage_obj::stage1,
    stage_obj::stage2,
    stage_obj::stage3
);
```

```
void processWorkflow(List<Runnable> workflow) {
    for (Runnable stage : workflow)
        stage.run();
}
```

If the methods are `static`, e.g. they don't need access to instance fields, your code would be:

```
List<Runnable> workflow = Arrays.asList(
    Stages::stage1,
    Stages::stage2,
    Stages::stage3
);
```

The `processWorkflow` method would still be the same.

As you can see, that closely matches your Python code, but it is fully type-safe.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23958814/functional-interface-that-takes-nothing-and-returns-nothing. Look at the comments on this similar answer. They are informative.

Answer (score 0):

I would use [reflection](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/javareflection-1536171.html):

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, NoSuchMethodException, SecurityException, IllegalAccessException, IllegalArgumentException, InvocationTargetException {
    Stages stage_obj = new Stages();

    Collection<java.lang.reflect.Method> workflow = new ArrayList<java.lang.reflect.Method>();
    workflow.add(stage_obj.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("stage1"));
    workflow.add(stage_obj.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("stage2"));
    workflow.add(stage_obj.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("stage3"));

    Iterator<java.lang.reflect.Method> workflowIterator = workflow.iterator();
    while(workflowIterator.hasNext()) {
        workflowIterator.next().invoke(stage_obj);
    }
}
```